# In a React App, where should you put files that are only used in tests (json...)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, jestjs, create-react-app

I've unit tests that utilize a common reference Json file. That file is used by multiple tests all throughout the app.

Can I simply create a folder "testFiles" and put my json file there? I don't want the json to be bundled when building for prod

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the answer is simple or I don't see whole picture yet.

When I need json files in my unit tests, I'm putting them into some `./test/mocks/..` subfolder and just importing them.

`import xxx from "../../mocks/yyy.json";`